# interaction term in a regression, drop stand alone coefficient

Tags: r

Using this interaction term in R yields coefficients on every variable within the interaction term, e.g

```
lm(y~dummy1*dummy2)
```

gives these three coefficients: `dummy1`, `dummy2` and `dummy1:dummy2`

Using the regression equation

```
lm(y~dummy1*dummy2*dummy3)
```

is there a way to only have coefficients on

`dummy1`, `dummy2`, and `dummy1*dummy2*dummy3`, but not `dummy3` as a standalone coefficient?

Comment: There are two approaches:  specify the model using `dummy1:dummy2:dummy3`, or use `I(dummy1*dummy2*dummy3)`.  Which is appropriate depends on the circumstances.  Your example isn't reproducible, so I can't tell which to recommend.

Comment: Won't these two approaches in fact give identical results?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't entirely clear, but I'll try.

First, it may help to note the difference between the `*` operator (interaction *plus all corresponding main effects and lower-level interactions*) and `:` (interactions only).

A testing framework:

```r
dd <- data.frame(dummy1=1:10, dummy2 = 1:10, dummy3 = 1:10)
f <- function(f) colnames(model.matrix(f, data  = dd))
```

```r
f(~dummy1*dummy2*dummy3)
[1] "(Intercept)"          "dummy1"               "dummy2"              
[4] "dummy3"               "dummy1:dummy2"        "dummy1:dummy3"       
[7] "dummy2:dummy3"        "dummy1:dummy2:dummy3"
```

Now try adding `- dummy3` to the end of the formula:

```r
f(~dummy1*dummy2*dummy3 - dummy3)
[1] "(Intercept)"          "dummy1"               "dummy2"              
[4] "dummy1:dummy2"        "dummy1:dummy3"        "dummy2:dummy3"       
[7] "dummy1:dummy2:dummy3"
```

This seems to work.

If you really only want the two main effects and the three-way interactions (which seems weird),

```r
f(~dummy1 + dummy2 + dummy1:dummy2:dummy3)
[1] "(Intercept)"          "dummy1"               "dummy2"              
[4] "dummy1:dummy2:dummy3"
```

Note that this will all be much harder/work less well with factor predictors.